# Redirect error to file

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-cmdlet

I'm writing a PowerShell script and one of its parts should add a new user to Active Directory.
I'm using the `New-ADUser` cmdlet and I want to redirect any errors (if it will produce any) to a file.
So I write

```
New-ADUser -smth -smth 2>> ./log.txt
```

But it creates only a blank `log.txt` file when I simulate error.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: What version of powershell are you using?

Comment: I'm using 4.0. The OS is Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: Ahh, it's because the error is thrown by the parser, not by `New-ADUser`. Change your statement to valid syntax and it'll work (eg. `New-ADUser -Identity "nonexistingusername"`)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I explained it wrong. I for eg, I do `New-ADUser -Identity "j" `. I received the error ` New-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Identity'..... ` and I want to write this message to the log.txt. I do ` New-ADUser -Identity "j" 2>> path\to\log.txt `. It creates the file but it is empty

Comment: Sorry, the `Identity` parameter was a bad example (`New-ADUser` doesn't have it). My point was that the output redirector only picks up the error stream from the cmdlet itself, not any error thrown by the environment (such as syntax errors for example). You can enclose the call in a scriptblock if you want to capture parsing errors as well: `&{New-ADUser -smt} 2>> error.log`

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much for your assistance. Have a great day =)

Answer (score 0):

Errors that are thrown by the cmdlet itself can be redirected like you tried:

```
New-Item -Type File C:\Windows\WinSxS\foo.txt 2>> error.log
```

Errors thrown by the environment (parser errors for instance) can only be redirected if you run the cmdlet in a nested context, e.g. a scriptblock:

```
& { New-Item -Foo } 2>> error.log
```