# Can't get New-ADUser result out from Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am looking for a way to redirect the result from New-ADUser to a file

Thats what i have tested: Run twice the following script

> New-ADUser -Name User64 | Out-File C:\Temp\test.txt

or

> New-ADUser -Name User64 2>&1 >> C:\Temp\test.txt

But none of this work, these just output an empty file and show the error in the Powershell

> New-ADUser : The specified account already exists
>   At line:1 char:11

rather than output in the test.txt file.

Any idea for this?

Thanks,
Derek

Comment: What data you want out of new-aduser cmdlet?

Comment: The error "New-ADUser: The specified account already exists ...." should be redirected to the test.txt file rather than in the Powershell console

Comment: New-ADUser 'UserName' -ErrorVariable ErrorItem


If you open $ErrorItem, you will get the error message

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162216/redirect-error-to-file has the same problem and a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with try/catch construct, like this:

```
try
{
    New-ADUser -Name User64 -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
    $Error[0].Exception.Message | Out-File C:\Temp\test.txt -Append
}
```